# I was wondering how I can change the source of an image using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am currently developing a memory game in JavaScript. It works so far, but I ran into a problem and I am not sure how to solve it. So the game begins where I make 6 images that all have the source as a red back card and once they get clicked they reveal the image beneath them. When I check if two cards are a match, I push the front of the card (using an expando property) into an array and check if the two values are the same. This array can only hold two values because the user can only reveal two cards at once when playing. However, if it's not a match, I'm having trouble setting the two revealed cards' sources back to the red card back. Here is what I have so far

```js
var arrCards = [];
var arrShowedCards = [];
//appendElements();
function init() {
  createCards();
  shuffleCards();
  appendElements();
}

function createCards() {
  var arrCardNames = ["Mouse", "Penguin", "Pop", "Mouse", "Penguin", "Pop"];
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    var card = document.createElement("IMG");
    card.src = "Images/red_back.png";
    card.className = "card";
    card.frontSrc = "Images/" + arrCardNames[i] + ".png";
    card.id = "card" + i;
    card.addEventListener("click", showCard);
    document.getElementById("cards").appendChild(card);
    arrCards.push(card);
  }
}

function shuffleCards() {
  for (let i = arrCards.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    const temp = arrCards[i];
    arrCards[i] = arrCards[j];
    arrCards[j] = temp;
  }
  return arrCards;

}

function appendElements() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arrCards.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("cards").appendChild(arrCards[i]);
  }
}

function showCard() {
  this.src = this.frontSrc;
  arrShowedCards.push(this.frontSrc);
  if (arrShowedCards.length === 2) {
    if (arrShowedCards[0] === arrShowedCards[1]) {
      console.log("Match!");
      arrShowedCards = [];
    } else {
      console.log("No match!");
      setTimeout(function() {

      }, 2000);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.card {
  width: 35%;
}

#cards {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
  row-gap: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change this license
Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Other/html.html to edit this template
-->
<html>

<head>
  <title>TODO supply a title</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body onload="init()">
  <section id="cards">
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

In the setTimeOut function is where I am putting the card that switches the source.
I tried doing `arrShowedCards[0].src = "Images/red_back.png"` and that wasn't working.
Anyone have a way I can approach this?

Comment: `arrShowedCards` doesn't contain the image, it contains the src URL: `arrShowedCards.push(this.frontSrc)`.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar I was able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

`arrShowedCards` doesn't contain the image elements, it contains the image URLs of the selected cards. So setting `arrShowedCards[0].src` doesn't change the image.

You can just set the `.img` of all the cards to the red back.

```js
function showCard() {
  this.src = this.frontSrc;
  arrShowedCards.push(this.frontSrc);
  if (arrShowedCards.length === 2) {
    if (arrShowedCards[0] === arrShowedCards[1]) {
      console.log("Match!");
      arrShowedCards = [];
    } else {
      console.log("No match!");
      setTimeout(function() {
        arrCards.forEach(card => card.src = 'Images/red_back.png');
      }, 2000);
    }
  }
}
```